# I want to Trim an output thats being parsed by XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have the current output :

> "File:/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf"."Permissions (Unix) (Unix)" ["0640"] does not have any flag ["World Execute", "World Read", "Owner Execute", "Group Execute", "Group Write", "Owner Write", "World Write"]

but I just wanted the:

> "File:/etc/snmp/ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

part of the equation..

how do I make my IF statement in java to check if the 'file:etc/snmp' is in the output and if it is, print the characters up until the ' "] ' part of the equation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String str = "...";
String path = str.split("\\.\"")[0];
```

Then `path` will contain `"File:/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf"`

Hope to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    String str = "...";
    if(str.contains("File:/etc/snmp/")){
        String exp= str.split("\".\"")[1];
        System.out.println(exp);
    }
```